# Internet Explorer 9 - website certificate expired

Tags: internet-explorer, ssl, certificate

My Internet Explorer 9, for every page, shows this messege to me:

> There is a problem with this website"s security certificate. The
>   security certificate presented by website has expired or is not yet
>   valid. Security certificate problems may indicate an attempt to fool
>   you or intercept any data you send to the server.  We recommend that
>   you close this webpage and do not continue to this website.
>
> Click here to close this webpage.
>   Continue to this website (not recommended)"

and afterwards it shows this :

> Internet Explorer blocked this website from displaying content with
>   security certificate errors
>   [show content]

Please help me to resolve this problem!

Comment: Is your computer's time set correctly?

Comment: [Certificate error with Internet Explorer 9](http://superuser.com/q/288459)